# How to iteratively add a column to a dataframe X based on the values of a separated dataframe y with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix, concatenation

I am struggling with this problem.

These are my initial matrices:

```
columnsx = {'X1':[6,11,17,3,12],'X2':[1,2,10,24,18],'X3':[8,14,9,15,7], 'X4':[22,4,20,16,5],'X5':[19,21,13,23,25]}
columnsy = {'y1':[0,1,1,2,0],'y2':[1,0,0,2,1]}
X = pd.DataFrame(columnsx)
y = pd.DataFrame(columnsy)
```

This is the final solution I am figuring out. It adds a column to X (called X_i), corresponding to the name of y with y value > 0. Therefore, it takes only the positive values of y (y>0) and rensitutes a binary vector with cardinality 2.

```
columnsx = {'X1':[11,17,3,6,3,12],'X2':[2,10,24,1,24,18],'X3':[14,9,15,8,15,7], 
            'X4':[4,20,16,22,16,5],'X5':[21,13,23,19,23,25], 'X_i':['y1','y1','y1','y2','y2','y2']}
columnsy = {'y':[1,1,2,1,2,1]}
X = pd.DataFrame(columnsx)
y = pd.DataFrame(columnsy)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt)

```
new_df = (df.melt(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('X')], 
                  var_name='X_y', value_name='y')
            .loc[lambda df: df['y'].gt(0)])

print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
   X1  X2  X3  X4  X5 X_y  y
1  11   2  14   4  21  y1  1
2  17  10   9  20  13  y1  1
3   3  24  15  16  23  y1  2
5   6   1   8  22  19  y2  1
8   3  24  15  16  23  y2  2
9  12  18   7   5  25  y2  1
```